# flex3 highlight the datagrid column

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How to highlight the data grid column?

Thanks.
AravindakumarThangaraju.

Comment: more detail please, are you trying to highlight on rollover like the rows or do you just want one column to be a particular color?

Comment: I just want one column to be a particular color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you creating your datagrid in mxml then just add

```
backgroundColor="0xFF0000"
```

to the

```
<mx:DatagridColumn>
```

tag to make the background red

if its in Actionscript its

```
MyDG.columns[0].setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xFF0000);
```

to make the first column background red.